# Calculate age from age given before

Tags: android, date

I am developing an Android app in which I have a module for cattle management.
Here an user can add some data(Type,Age,Gender etc.) about his/her animals.

Here suppose user has entered age of his animal in this format: 2 years 3 months
then whenever user queries for this animal, the age should be updated.

I have found some solutions to find age from birthdate by subtracting birthdate from current date. But here I can't ask users to fill their animal's birthdate.

So is there any way I can programatically find animal's age from age given while filling a form.

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: put a timestamp when they enter the data. next time its loaded, take current time minus the time stamp and add that to the info they entered...

Comment: yes i know that logic. but here i also will have to keep in mind that some months have 31 days while some have 30.

Comment: SYSDATE (2013 years 3 months) - date(2 years 3 months)  = 2013 -3 = 2010 years 0 months. Use the years and months as keys and just substract the simple numbers.

Comment: I tried this: but its giving me age from birthdate. http://www.androidsnippets.com/calculate-age

Answer (score 0):

Store a time stamp in utc time then truncate the accuracy you don't need